# Hecke equidistribution for $L^1$ functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, ergodic-theory, automorphic-forms

Put shortly, the question is, does the Hecke equidistribution hold for $L^1$ functions?

To be specific, the version of H.E. I need is

$T_N f \rightarrow \int f d\mu$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$,

where the relevant space is $X_n := SL(n,\mathbb{Z}) \backslash SL(n, \mathbb{R})$, $T_N$ is the Hecke operator, $\mu$ the right-invariant probability measure on $X_n$, and $f$ a "nice" function on $X_n$.

I know this holds for $f \in L^2$. If it fails for general $L^1$ functions I'd like to have some insights as to why not. To my lament, it seems in most of the literature H.E. is stated for only compactly supported continuous functions.

Comment: Do you mean convergence in $L^2$ (resp. $L^1$) when $f\in L^2$ (resp. $f\in L^1$)? Note that everywhere pointwise convergence fails in general (e.g. let $f$ be the characteristic function of the union of Hecke points coming from a fixed $x\in X_n$).

Comment: Yes I do mean convergence in $L^1$ when $f \in L^1$. More precisely, $T_Nf \rightarrow \left(\int fd\mu\right)\mathbf{1}$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is the constant function equal to 1 a.e.

Comment: So you don't need convergence at almost every point, right? I am asking, because this is a much stronger statement than convergence in $L^1$ (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem).

Comment: That is a very good point, I realize you're absolutely right in suggesting that I really want some pointwise convergence. In fact, convergence at any single point $x \in X$ is all I need. I guess I wish it holds for a broader range of functions than $C_c(X_n)$ --- cannot see a reason why not.

Comment: If the automorphic spectral decomposition of $f$ converges sufficiently rapidly, then you have pointwise convergence everywhere, because pointwise convergence holds for cusp forms and incomplete Eisenstein series (I think this is how the proof goes). So all you need is that $f$ is sufficiently smooth, meaning that the first few derivatives lie in $L^2$. How many derivatives you need depends on $n$ and how you can bound the cusp forms and incomplete Eisenstein series pointwise (to show that the tail of the spectral decomposition contributes little). For cups forms see arXiv:1712.05065

Comment: P.S. The arXiv preprint I linked in my previous comment is for spherical functions, i.e., it can only be used on the space $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})\backslash\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{SO}_n(\mathbb{R})$.